# Icons not showing on enterprise deploy

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, enterprise, ipa

I added to png files called allegroicon.png ( 57x57 and 117x117 ) to make plist.

When clicking target I see the launch images and icons on the screen.

I also set the icon names in my plist.

When deploying for distribution I set the url images and I have tried without specifying them, but when downloading it just shows a grey icon.

On the Simulator I see my icon graphics.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just guessing: Icons must be 114x114 not 117x117. May be it is related to this size issue.

Comment: I would check that you can access these images via their URL in your browser. If you can't view the images, there is an issue with your web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After releasing the cache, I can see the icons and making sure their names or correct.